# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.api'

Tags: keras, docker-compose, dockerfile, airflow

I'm using Macbook Pro to run a server that was used to deploy on AWS. I have received an unknown error when running airflow. I did install Keras.

**dockerfile**

`RUN pip install "Keras==2.3.1"`

`RUN pip install "apache-airflow[celery,devel,postgres,redis,s3,ssh]==1.10.9"`

`RUN pip install "keras-models==0.0.7"`

But we are getting the missing keras.api module. I can't find keras.api was used anywhere.

```
ml.scheduler_1   |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ml.scheduler_1   |   File "/robo/airflow/dags/general/video_migration.py", line 5, in <module>
ml.scheduler_1   |     from flows.operators import video_process as videos
ml.scheduler_1   |   File "/robo/flows/operators/video_process.py", line 11, in <module>
ml.scheduler_1   |     from serving.models.ali_audit import AliVideoAbuseDetection
ml.scheduler_1   |   File "/robo/serving/models/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
ml.scheduler_1   |     _module = loader.find_module(module_name).load_module(module_name)
ml.scheduler_1   |   File "/robo/serving/models/places365.py", line 8, in <module>
ml.scheduler_1   |     from keras_models.models.pretrained import vgg16_places365
ml.scheduler_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras_models/models/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
ml.scheduler_1   |     from .linear import build as LinearModel
ml.scheduler_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras_models/models/linear.py", line 2, in <module>
ml.scheduler_1   |     from keras import Model
ml.scheduler_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
ml.scheduler_1   |     from . import utils
ml.scheduler_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
ml.scheduler_1   |     from .vis_utils import model_to_dot
ml.scheduler_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/vis_utils.py", line 7, in <module>
ml.scheduler_1   |     from ..models import Model
ml.scheduler_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 12, in <module>
ml.scheduler_1   |     from .engine.training import Model
ml.scheduler_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
ml.scheduler_1   |     from .training import Model
ml.scheduler_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 14, in <module>
ml.scheduler_1   |     from . import training_utils
ml.scheduler_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 17, in <module>
ml.scheduler_1   |     from .. import metrics as metrics_module
ml.scheduler_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/metrics.py", line 1850, in <module>
ml.scheduler_1   |     BaseMeanIoU = tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU
ml.scheduler_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py", line 62, in __getattr__
ml.scheduler_1   |     module = self._load()
ml.scheduler_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py", line 45, in _load
ml.scheduler_1   |     module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
ml.scheduler_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
ml.scheduler_1   |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ml.scheduler_1   | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.api'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use official Docker Image of Apache Airflow as a base ? Which version ?

There are two reasons it might be the case that I can think of:

1. you RUN pip install after switiching to root user. Don't. PIP packages should be installed as `airflow` user and in case you switched to `root` user before to install some extra stuff, you need to switch back to `airflow` user.

See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html#examples-of-image-extending for examples

2. If you use 2.0.0 (which you really should not as there were a number of releases afer that)  then you also need to add `--user` when installing PIP packages. This has been enabled by default for 2.0.1 and you do not need to add `--user` for 2.0.1 onwards.

Comment: We are using dockerfile to install. I've edited the post. Airflow is 1.10.9.

Comment: And RUN pip install "keras-models==0.0.7"

Comment: Airflow 1.10.9 is extremely old and there were many security issues fixed and bugfixes. Actually the whole Airflow 1.10 line has reached end-of-life in June 2021. I heartily recommend to migrate to Airflow 2. I think you will not get too much help for such an old version.

Comment: I don't think it is an Airflow issue because it was running fine on our AWS server. I am trying to install it and run it on my Macbook Pro.